# Exception occurs when trying to connect to MS SQLSERVER from android with Exposed

Tags: sql-server, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

```
import android.os.AsyncTask
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Table
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.selectAll
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.transaction

class DatabaseConnect : AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

    object Users : Table() {
        val id = uuid("ID").autoIncrement().primaryKey() // Column<uuid>
        val email = varchar("Email", 50) // Column<String>

    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): String? {
        try {
            val db = Database.connect("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.100.200;integratedSecurity=false;encrypt=false; trustServerCertificate=true;",
                "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
                user = "<myuser>", password = "<mypassword>")

            transaction(db) {
            for (u in Users.selectAll()) {
                    var i: Int = 0
                    val j = i++
                }
            }
        } catch (exception: Exception){
            print(exception)
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

When I run the application the followin exception occurs:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>           Process: hu.kovax.empmobile, PID: 28856
>           java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:399)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
>               ...
>       ...
>           Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
>               at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:385)
>               at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:226)
>               at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1802)

The SQLSERVER is up and alive.

I have found answers to other questions that might be related, one suggests to somehow disable conscrypt layer:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/issues/177

Is there a way to disable conscrypt layer in Exposed?

Comment: 192.168.100.200 looks like an IP on a local LAN. Is the Android device connected to the same LAN network?

Comment: Yes it is connected to the same network